# Error when trying to use Verilog from VHDL in Lattice Radiant

Tags: vhdl, verilog

I'm trying to use an IP generated with the IP Catalog in Radiant, which was only available as Verilog, from my VHDL top level entity. I use it like this:

```
ebr_inst : ebr port map(....
```

The Verilog entity starts like this:

```
module ebr (clk_i, clk_en_i, wr_en_i, wr_data_i, addr_i, rd_data_o);
```

But when I try to synthesize it, I get this error:

```
ERROR - w:/projects/ice40serialtest/source/top.vhd(71):
ebr is not a component. VHDL-1235
```

I can use other VHDL entities in my project without a problem. This is the full project: http://www.frank-buss.de/tmp/ram-test.zip

Comment: Did you declare the component before using it?

Comment: No, but I didn't do this for my other VHDL entities either, the synthesis tool should be smart enough to figure this out. But I tried it, found the template for it in ebr/misc/ebr_tmpl.vhd, and now it compiles. But maybe someone has a better solution, I don't like code duplication and unnecessary component declarations.

Comment: They are declared, they're part of the ICE package. If you don't declare your component, your file cannot be compiled.

Comment: In which package their are declared? "use ice.all" doesn't work.
But maybe it really needs an extra component declaration, because it can't figure this out from Verilog files for VHDL. But at least for my other VHDL entities I don't need the extra duplicate component declaration in my top level entity.

Comment: You either need a component declaration, such as with your RGB driver and RAM, which have these declaration in the ICE package, or you need an entity declaration such as with your rs232 RX and TX submodules. The ERB had neither, but uses component syntax for its instantiation without declaration. I'd read up on VHDL for a bit.

Comment: Yes, I always forget all the VHDL details, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I found the problem: I used `ebr_inst : ebr`. If you write it like this, you need to declare the component. But if your write `ebr_inst : entity ebr`, then the ebr component declaration is not needed.